# Unique clicks for Quick links

Tags: branch.io

I have used a quick link from branch.io as a click through URL for an ad running via google ad manager. How do I get unique clicks for the quick link? Does unique click means unique user clicked on ad? Click numbers in google ad manager are not matching with the clicks recorded in branch. Please help me find out unique clicks for quick links

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Quick Links in Google ACI/ACE campaigns. Google is a [SAN partner](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/self-attributing-networks-sans) and this is a linkless integration.

Briefly explaining that SAN partners like Google AdWords/ Facebook integration are different from conventional non-SAN partners, where we send conversion data to SAN partners and they will claim the install/ Events according to their conversion logic and respond to us via API. Branch then analyses the data from all the partners and attributes the same Install/ Event based on last-touch attribution logic.

Please follow the [this](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/google-ads-overview) docs that should help you in setting up the integration. Following the above guide, you can run a test campaign to compare the data on both platforms.